# VB.NET Call Sub using variable

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to Call a Public Sub by using a variable but can't seem to find the correct way of doing it. If I were to do in VBA then it's quite simple and would be:

```
Application.Run([fnd], [FormulaCell])
```

How would this translate to VB.NET?

I have read in other places about using a CallByName but I can't seem to apply it correctly to my code. This is what I have tried:

```
Dim MF As New MyProject.Modify_Formula
CallByName(MF, fnd(FormulaCell), CallType.Method)
```

When I try this method I get an error saying: Value of type 'Range' cannot be converted to 'Integer'. This error message is refering to (FormulaCell).

Can someone please help with this?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? There can be valid reasons but people often think they need to do things like this when they don't.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for the `CallByName` method? The second argument should be a `String` containing the name of the method to call. Does `fnd(FormulaCell)` return a `String` containing the name of a method?

Comment: fnd is a string. The FormulaCell part is a range that is passed through to the Sub that is being called. However, this is where I am getting the error as it is saying the range "FormulaCell" cannot be converted to integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much playing around with this, I found the solution. See below for the correct syntax.

```
Dim PMF As New Part_Modify_Formula
CallByName(PMF, fnd, CallType.Method, FormulaCell)
```

The range FormulaCell needed to be moved from the ProcName section to the Args section.